# import AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'

Tags: python, import, module

```
_submodule_exports = {
        '.foo' : ['Foo'],
        '.bar' : ['Bar']
        }

_submodule_by_name = {
        name: modulename
        for modulename in _submodule_exports
        for name in _submodule_exports[modulename] }

import types
import sys
import importlib

class OnDemandModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        modulename = _submodule_by_name.get(name)
        if modulename:
            module = importlib.import_module(modulename, __package__)
            print('Loaded', name)
            value = getattr(module, name)
            setattr(self, name ,value)
            return value
        raise AttributeError('No attribute %s' % name)

# old_module = sys.modules[__name__]
print sys.modules[__name__]

newmoudle = OnDemandModule(__name__)
newmoudle.__dict__.update(globals())
newmoudle.__all__ = list(_submodule_by_name)
sys.modules[__name__] = newmoudle
# the following line cause the error
maintain_module = sys.modules[__name__]
```

The code above is from __init__.py in a directory named "cycles_import". And when I import this module I get this:

[image: screenshot showing AttributeError]

I did an "import sys" module at the very beginning in this .py file. Why is "sys" not identified as an imported module?

Comment: Can't reproduce; this code works fine for me.

Comment: I run this code in python2.7 not python3.x environment. Maybe the this reason?

Comment: It's because the `sys.modules[__name__] = newmoudle` has a side-effect of clobbering `__name__` — see answer to duplicate question.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks a lots!